# Latent time-series with multiple observations per time point

Tags: time-series, latent-variable, weights, survey-weights

I have a latent time-series $\psi_t$ where for each time point $t$ I have multiple observations $y_t$, generated from a distribution dependent on $\psi_t$. The number of observations $n_t$ some time point changes for each $t$. Importantly, when $n_t$ is larger, the latent time-series should change more than if $n_t$ is small.

A possible simple set-up could be:

$\psi_t\sim AR(1)$

$y_{ti} \sim N(\psi_t, \sigma^2), ~~~~i = 1, \dots, n_t.$

A state-space model approach can allow me a latent time-series, but still assumes one observation from it for each $t$. I can run a hierarchical model so as to shrink each estimate $\psi_t$ more with smaller $n_t$, but then we ignore the time-series structure. I've searched a lot for a good solution, but have so far come up with nothing.

I'm looking for a simple model that is implemented in R or Python, The solutions I have come up with are:

1. Model a latent time-series where the latent variable is measured by multiple observations at each time point.
2. Run a regular time-series model, but use $n_t$ as a weight for each time point. This seems very simple (and easy to implement in any likelihood-based estimation), but I have surprisingly found no time-series implementation allowing weights.

Either one would work just as well, but I would also be OK with some pragmatic approximation to the problem. My questions about either of these, then, are:

- Is there a common name for such a model?
- Is it implemented in R or Python or anywhere?

Comment: By the way, my best attempt so far is to build the model customly in Stan, but this is difficult to work with and adapt, non-standard, and does not work as well as I would hope. The problem seems simple enough that an out-of-the-box solution is likely to be available. 

However, searching for weighted time-series is difficult because a common forecasting problem is giving lower importance to less recent observations, such as in Exponential Smoothing. However, here we wish to give all time points a weights such as a survey weight, because they represent the number of observations at that time